# Accessing Python CLI arguments without dot

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm using `argparse` for my Python CLI as follows:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser.add_argument('--myarg', type=str, help="Dummy arg")
args = parser.parse_args()

# access with dot notation
print(args.myarg)
```

This works fine. However, I now want to add an argument called `--continue`. Trying to access the arg with `args.continue` gives me a syntax error.

Is there any other way to access CLI args other than the dot notation? I tried dict-like access `args['continue']` but that gives me `TypeError: 'Namespace' object is not subscriptable`.
Do I really have to think of another CLI arg name?

Comment: You get the syntax error because 'continue' is a reserved word in python.  The dot syntax requires that the argument name be a valid python variable name.

Comment: With the `dest` parameter you can specify a different arg name while still allowing your users to use '--continue'.  `metavar` gives even more control over the help display.  You are never forced to use an awkward argument name.

Comment: True, that's a good hint about the `dest` parameter - I forgot about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `vars()` returns a dictionary form of an object (like `args`), letting you do exactly what you tried.

```py
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print(args['continue'])
```

Alternatively, you can get the attribute from the object directly with the `getattr` builtin function:

```py
args = parser.parse_args()

print(getattr(args, 'continue')
```